# I wonder if the two codes have the same behavior

Tags: java, exception, option-type

Both codes have behavior that throws an exception if the value doesn't exist.

```java
Optional<FreePosts> byId = Optional.ofNullable(freePostsRepository.findById(id))
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

```java
FreePosts byId = freePostsRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

I would like to know the difference between the two codes.

Comment: No, they do not have the same behaviour, the first one wraps an optional inside another optional and would only throw an exception if `findById` returns `null`, which it does not do. The second snippet is correct.

Comment: first snippet will throw `NoSuchElementException` exception when element returned by `findById` is null, second one will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Assuming that the return type is an `Optional`, then `findById` should never return a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

> Both codes have behavior that throws an exception if the value doesn't exist.

In fact, that is not true.  They don't both behave that way.

---

One of those two versions is incorrect, but which one it is depends on the declared return type of `findById` is.

- If the return type is `FreePosts`, then the second version does not compile, and it is therefore incorrect.

  The first version is equivalent to this:

  ```
   FreePosts byId = freePostsRepository.findById(id);
   if (byId == null) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
   }
  ```

  In my opinion, it would be better to write an explicit throw in this case, not least because you can include a message.
- If the return type `Optional<FreePost>` then the second version is correct<sup>1</sup>.

  In this case, the first version is going to throw an exception if and only if `findById` returns a `null`.  But if `findById` is written correctly, it won't ever return `null`.  (Instead, if should return an empty `Optional<FreePosts>` instance.)  So:

  - If `findById` doesn't have a bug that causes it to return `null`, the first version is not going to throw a `NoSuchElementException`, and therefore the `ofNullable(...)` and the `orElseThrow(...)` are pointless.
  - If there is a bug in `findById` that causes it to return `null`, throwing `NoSuchElementException` is obscuring the bug.

  In conclusion the first version is incorrect.

---

<sup>1 - I guess it is possible that the designer of the repository API has specified that `Optional<FreePosts> findById(...)` *should* return a `null` value instead of an `Optional`.  But that would be a huge mistake, IMO.</sup>